# Android market "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

Tags: android-manifest, google-play

There is a contradiction between what the Developer Console tells me, and what the Market tells me.

I just uploaded an APK to the market, after adding a couple of items to the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"/> 

android:screenOrientation="landscape"

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

I have an HTC Desire Bravo, and a Sony GoogleTV.

The market says "This app is incompatible with all of your devices.", giving the devices as "Telstra Htc_bravo" and "Sony NSZ-GS7/GX70".

The Developer Console -> APK section -> device compatability lists "HTCDesire– bravo" as compatible. (But "Google TVNSZ-GS7/GX70– NSZGS7" and "HTCDesire– bravoc" as incompatible.)

I can load and run the app on both (GoogleTV from USB stick, HTC Bravo from eclipse).

Yes, the new version of the app has uploaded to the market.

Can anyone shed some light on why the HTC Bravo is OK in the console, but not in the market?

Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mancaladroid"
android:versionCode="6"
android:versionName="1.5" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"/> 
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_mancala_121229"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MancalaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

No response from the forum, so I experimented.

Executive summary: “faketouch” feature not available on devices I’d expect it, and it’s hard to know what exact type of phone you have.

In more detail…

Landscape orientation and screenSize: I reverted these to state in previous versions (absent). It made no difference. I put them back in.

I removed the "android.hardware.faketouch" requirement – bingo! The count of supported devices jumped from 1350 to 2829.

The Bravoc and Sony GoogleTV are now listed on the Developer Console as supported. The app is available on the market for both of my devices.

Puzzling – where-ever I look (eg, phone’s info), I cannot see any indication that I have a HTC Desire bravoc rather than a bravo. My model number is HTC Desire A8183.

I hope that helps someone who hits a similar problem!